# Absolute value of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, absolute-value

Let $f,g,h:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, then is it true the following:
$$
fh=gh\Longrightarrow f|h|=g|h|?
$$
where $|z|=z^++z^-$ and $z^+,z^-$ are respectively the positive and negative part of a function $z$. I don't think  itis true, I have tried to find some counterexamples using indicator functions, but I have not managed to disprove it (or to prove it).

Comment: Does $fh$ denote here the function $x\mapsto f(x)h(x)$ or does it denote the function $x\mapsto f(h(x))$?

Answer (score 0):

It is true. Just consider the  cases $h>0, h<0$ and $h=0$ to prove it.

Comment: sorry, but what happens if I have a function $h$ which is positive, negative and zero in different parts of its domain? I mean: are the three cases you have proposed exhaustive? Or you mean I should decompose the function $f$ in its positiv and negative parts? Because I have tried the fact that $h=h^+-h^-$, but I have not managed to prove the claim above. Thanks :)

Comment: To prove that $f|h|=g|h|$ you have to prove that $f(x)|h(x)|=g(x)|h(x)|$ for every fixed real number $x$.  You can certainly split the proof into the cases $h(x)>0, h(x)<0$ and $h(x)=0$. @anonymous

Answer (score 0):

It is not true if $fh$ stands for composition $f\circ h$.

Let $h$ be prescribed by $x\mapsto1$ if $x<0$ and $x\mapsto -2$ otherwise.

Let $f$ be the identity.

Let $g$ be prescribed by $g(1)=1$, $g(-2)=-2$ and $x\mapsto 0$ if $x\notin\{1,-2\}$.

Then $f\circ h=g\circ h$ but not $f\circ|h|=g\circ|h|$.

Note that e.g. $f\circ|h|(0)=f(|h|(0))=f(2)=2$ and $g\circ|h|(0)=g(|h|(0))=g(2)=0$.

Comment: Why do you think that $fg$ denotes $f\circ g$ here?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I do *not exclude* it. That's all. This because I can imagine that this problem indeed rises in that context. The OP will bring clarity I hope.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Especially the words in the question: "I don't think it is true" pointed (for me) in this direction.

Comment: Perhaps - considering that the OP had problems with the trivial proof in the other answer it seems like his not thinking it's true says very little...